# Providing access to different data stores with the Repository Pattern

Tags: c#, .net, oop, design-patterns, software-design

I've been trying to learn how the service layer and repository pattern work. So far I've written a service layer and a simple repository pattern interface. However, I often see articles stating that the repository pattern allows for being able to swap in and out different data stores without the consuming code having to be changed.

In my case I want to be able to support reading and writing the application data to CSV and/or XML files. This is the part where I do not understand how to properly implement this with the repository pattern. Should I have a repository per data store?

```
ProductCsvRepository : IProductRepository
ProductXmlRepository : IProductRepository
```

However if I do this then the service layer would have to be aware of the underlying data store, which breaks the idea of being able to easily swap in and out different data stores.

Would I then have to have a service layer that looks like this?

```
private readonly IProductXmlRepository _productXmlRepository;
private readonly IProductCsvRepository _productCsvRepository;

public ProductService()
{
    _productXmlRepository = new IProductXmlRepository();
    _productCsvRepository = new IProductCsvRepository();
}

public ICollection<Product> GetAllXml()
{
    return _productXmlRepository.GetAllCsv();
}

public ICollection<Product> GetAll()
{
    return _productCsvRepository.GetAllXml();
}
```

This then raises two questions:

- Surely this then breaks the idea of the consuming code needing to know what the data store is?
- What about in the situations where the consuming code **does** need to know about the data store, such as for "File > Export As" type functionality? Should export functionality actually be a different service that utilises the appropriate CSV or XML service?

I think I am definetly not understanding how to correctly implement a repository patten and a service layer. How should I actually design repository patten and service layer?

Comment: The constructor of your Service should accept an `IProductRepository`. Now your service object will be made of either `ProductCsvRepository` or `ProductXmlRepository`. At runtime, you can send in either of the two to perform `IProductRepository` operations.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at dependency injection and the plug-in pattern. They support injecting a concrete implementation of a repository. Your service layer then has only one reference to `IProductRepository` and a concrete repository gets injected. Something along the lines of this:

```
public class ProductService
{
    private readonly IProductRepository _productRepository;

    public ProductService(IProductRepository productRepository)
    {
        _productRepository = productRepository;
    }
}


public class ConsumingClass {
{
    private readonly IProductService _productService = new ProductService(new ProductXmlRepository());

    // methods to use the the product service
}
```

But better would be to use a inversion of control container like NInject or SimpleInjector. Those frameworks can be used to link abstract classes (`IProductRepository`) to concrete classes (`ProductXmlRepository` or `ProductXmlRepository`) based on xml configurations.

Answer (score 0):

Your application's solution should be structured following the Dependency Inversion Principle (http://deviq.com/dependency-inversion-principle/), so that there are at minimum three projects:

- Core
- Infrastructure
- Your UI project

All (or nearly all) of your interfaces should be declared in Core (e.g. IProductRepository). Your interface implementations belong in Infrastructure, which references Core. Finally, your UI project should reference Core, but not necessarily Infrastructure (learn how to use types from a project without referencing it: http://blog.falafel.com/use-types-from-project-without-referencing/).

With this architecture in place, you can use dependency injection (http://deviq.com/dependency-injection/) to inject the desired implementation of a given type at runtime, which provides great flexibility and testability.

**Setting up your solution with the proper dependencies between projects is critical** to being successful with this approach, since a traditional UI -> Business Layer -> Data Layer setup will not allow you to invert dependencies. Once your solution is set up in this manner, you should follow the Explicit Dependencies Principle (http://deviq.com/explicit-dependencies-principle/) in all of your UI and service code.